# How to copy file from internal storage to external storage Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-storage

**Expected outcome:**

I would want to copy and move file from internal storage to external storage to downloads folder in order for user to have access to it.

**What I've tried:**

```
File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "test");
```

```
copyFile(attachmentFile.getAbsolutePath(), out.getAbsolutePath());
```

```
private void copyFile(String from, String to) {
        try {
            int bytesum = 0;
            int byteread = 0;
            File oldfile = new File(from);
            if (oldfile.exists()) {
                Log.d("ifExists", "Old file exists! ");
                InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
                FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(to);
                Log.d("ifExists", "copyFile: " + fs);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1444];
                while ((byteread = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    bytesum += byteread;
                    fs.write(buffer, 0, byteread);
                }
                inStream.close();
                fs.close();
                Log.d("ifExists", "File has been created ");
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**My outcome:**

File is being saved correctly to the internal storage but seems like I can't save to the downloads folder.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Downloadtest: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Comment: `File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "test");` Cange the `+` in a `,`.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Downloadtest` Well... Did you really mean that? Or `/storage/emulated/0/Download/test`?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is mistake in your file path. please check below file path and replace your file path with below file path. you forgot to add "/" this in your file path.

```
File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/test");
```